# UIImage Methods not getting called

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to manipulate UIImage Object on the view. But when I try to call any method on UIImage class, it throws exception

```
2013-02-14 15:24:42.301 Test[4685:19a03] -[UIImage scaleToSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94642c0 
2013-02-14 15:24:42.303 Test[4685:19a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage scaleToSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94642c0'
*** First throw call stack:`
(0x1cc1012 0x1ae6e7e 0x1d4c4bd 0x1cb0bbc 0x1cb094e 0x47ee9 0x47bc0 0xb0f817 0xb0f882 0xb0fb2a 0xb26ef5 0xb26fdb 0xb27286 0xb27381 0xb27eab 0xb27fc9 0xb28055 0xc2d3ab 0xa7e92d 0x1afa6b0 0x5c3fc0 0x5b833c 0x5b8150 0x5360bc 0x537227 0x5378e2 0x1c89afe 0x1c89a3d 0x1c66f61 0x1c66e1b 0x39117e3 0x3911668 0xa2e65c 0x31fcd 0x29d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
 UIImage *test = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image0.jpg"];
    [test scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0f, 40.0f)];
```

Comment: UIImage does not implement scaleToSize: method. You are trying to use some 3rd party library may be?

Comment: remove scaleToSize because its not supported for UIImage

Comment: Didn't you get a warning on the `scaleToSize` line?

Comment: Yes I'm using 3rd party library filtrr: https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr.

Comment: paste code of scaleToSize..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [UIImage's class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You won't find the method you are looking for. Maybe you forgot to add a category you are using like (for example):

```
#import "UIImage+Scale.h"
```

Comment: Again I said `#import "UIImage+Scale.h"`just to give you an example of a possible category that would allow you to scale `UIImage`s...

Answer (score -1):

FIRST DEFINE THE IMAGE SIZE THEN SCALE IT.

```
UIImage *test = [[UIImage alloc] init;
test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image0.jpg"];
[test scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(40.0f, 40.0f)];
```

Try this line of code.Or use this image in UIImageView

Comment: Problem is with `scaleToSize`. It isn't implemented in UIImage.

Comment: use this for image   Image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);